# Sum columns of pandas dataframe with blank data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe with blank spaces in. (These blank spaces are important for a later application). For example, my dataframe is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df = df.append([['Variable A','',435.65]], ignore_index = True)
df = df.append([['Variable B',324,'']], ignore_index = True)
df = df.append([['Variable C','',300]], ignore_index = True)
df.columns = ['Type','DR','CR']
```

I would like to find the total of the columns, ignoring blank spaces. I have tried the following:

```
print(df)    
print('TOTAL DR ',df['DR'].sum(numeric_only=True))
print('TOTAL CR ',df['CR'].sum(numeric_only=True))
```

But I’m recieving an error message:
Not implemented error: Series.sum does not implement numeric only

How would I go about getting the column totals? Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `print("TOTAL DR = ",pd.to_numeric(df['DR'], errors='coerce').sum().astype(int))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `sum` strings versus integers.

Parse your `''` entries as `np.nan` or just `0` first then do the sum.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([])
>>> df = df.append([['Variable A','',435.65]], ignore_index = True)
>>> df = df.append([['Variable B',324,'']], ignore_index = True)
>>> df = df.append([['Variable C','',300]], ignore_index = True)
>>> df.columns = ['Type','DR','CR']
>>>
>>>
>>> df
         Type   DR      CR
0  Variable A       435.65
1  Variable B  324
2  Variable C          300
>>>>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['DR'] = np.where(df['DR'] == '', [0],df['DR'])
>>> df
         Type   DR      CR
0  Variable A    0  435.65
1  Variable B  324
2  Variable C    0     300
>>> print('TOTAL DR ',df['DR'].sum())
TOTAL DR  324
```

Another option is to use `pd.to_numeric` before doing the summation.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([])
>>> df = df.append([['Variable A','',435.65]], ignore_index = True)
>>> df = df.append([['Variable B',324,'']], ignore_index = True)
>>> df = df.append([['Variable C','',300]], ignore_index = True)
>>> df.columns = ['Type','DR','CR']
>>> print('TOTAL DR ',pd.to_numeric(df['DR']).sum())
TOTAL DR  324.0
>>> print('TOTAL DR ',pd.to_numeric(df['CR']).sum())
TOTAL DR  735.65
```